# Detecting pattern in OHLC data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, stumpy

I have the following set of OHLC data:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 6, 30), '0.00013449', '0.00013866', '0.00013440', '0.00013857', '430864.00000000', 1593579599999, '59.09906346', 1885, '208801.00000000', '28.63104974', '0', 3.0336828016952944], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 7, 0), '0.00013854', '0.00013887', '0.00013767', '0.00013851', '162518.00000000', 1593581399999, '22.48036621', 809, '78014.00000000', '10.79595625', '0', -0.02165439584236435], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 7, 30), '0.00013851', '0.00013890', '0.00013664', '0.00013780', '313823.00000000', 1593583199999, '43.21919087', 1077, '157083.00000000', '21.62390537', '0', -0.5125983683488642], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 8, 0), '0.00013771', '0.00013818', '0.00013654', '0.00013707', '126925.00000000', 1593584999999, '17.44448931', 428, '56767.00000000', '7.79977280', '0', -0.46474475346744676], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 8, 30), '0.00013712', '0.00013776', '0.00013656', '0.00013757', '62261.00000000', 1593586799999, '8.54915420', 330, '26921.00000000', '3.69342184', '0', 0.3281796966161107], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 9, 0), '0.00013757', '0.00013804', '0.00013628', '0.00013640', '115154.00000000', 1593588599999, '15.80169390', 510, '52830.00000000', '7.24924784', '0', -0.8504761212473579], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 9, 30), '0.00013640', '0.00013675', '0.00013598', '0.00013675', '66186.00000000', 1593590399999, '9.02070446', 311, '24798.00000000', '3.38107106', '0', 0.25659824046919455], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 10, 0), '0.00013655', '0.00013662', '0.00013577', '0.00013625', '56656.00000000', 1593592199999, '7.71123423', 367, '27936.00000000', '3.80394497', '0', -0.2196997436836377], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 10, 30), '0.00013625', '0.00013834', '0.00013625', '0.00013799', '114257.00000000', 1593593999999, '15.70194874', 679, '56070.00000000', '7.70405037', '0', 1.2770642201834814], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 11, 0), '0.00013812', '0.00013822', '0.00013630', '0.00013805', '104746.00000000', 1593595799999, '14.39147417', 564, '46626.00000000', '6.39959586', '0', -0.05068056762237037], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 11, 30), '0.00013805', '0.00013810', '0.00013720', '0.00013732', '37071.00000000', 1593597599999, '5.10447229', 231, '16349.00000000', '2.25258584', '0', -0.5287939152480996], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 12, 0), '0.00013733', '0.00013741', '0.00013698', '0.00013724', '27004.00000000', 1593599399999, '3.70524540', 161, '15398.00000000', '2.11351192', '0', -0.06553557125171522], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 12, 30), '0.00013724', '0.00013727', '0.00013687', '0.00013717', '27856.00000000', 1593601199999, '3.81864840', 140, '11883.00000000', '1.62931445', '0', -0.05100553774411102], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 13, 0), '0.00013716', '0.00013801', '0.00013702', '0.00013741', '83867.00000000', 1593602999999, '11.54964001', 329, '42113.00000000', '5.80085155', '0', 0.18226888305628908], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 13, 30), '0.00013741', '0.00013766', '0.00013690', '0.00013707', '50299.00000000', 1593604799999, '6.90474065', 249, '20871.00000000', '2.86749244', '0', -0.2474346845207872], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 14, 0), '0.00013707', '0.00013736', '0.00013680', '0.00013704', '44745.00000000', 1593606599999, '6.13189248', 205, '14012.00000000', '1.92132206', '0', -0.02188662727072625], [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 14, 30), '0.00013704', '0.00014005', '0.00013703', '0.00013960', '203169.00000000', 1593608399999, '28.26967457', 904, '150857.00000000', '21.00600041', '0', 1.8680677174547595]]
```

That looks like this:
[image]

I'm trying to detect a pattern that looks like the one above in other sets of OHLC data. It doesn't have to be the same, it only needs to be **similar**, i.e. the number of candles doesn't have to be the same. Just the shape needs to be similar.

**The problem:**
I don't know where to start to accomplish this. I know it's not easy to do, but I'm sure there is a way to do this.

**What I have tried:**
Until now, I only managed to cut away manually the OHLC data that I don't need, so that I can only have the patterns I want. Then, I plotted it using a Pandas dataframe:

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([x[:6] for x in OHLC], 
                          columns=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])

format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format=format)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']))
df["Open"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Open"],errors='coerce')
df["High"] = pd.to_numeric(df["High"],errors='coerce')
df["Low"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Low"],errors='coerce')
df["Close"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Close"],errors='coerce')
df["Volume"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Volume"],errors='coerce')


mpf.plot(df, type='candle', figscale=2, figratio=(50, 50))
```

**What I thought:** A possible solution to this problem is using Neural Networks, so I would have to feed images of the patterns I want to a NN and let the NN loop though other charts and see if it can find the patterns I specified. Before going this way, I was looking for simpler solutions, since I don't know much about Neural Networks and I don't know what kind of NN I would need to do and what tools would I be supposed to use.

Another solution I was thinking about was the following: I would need, somehow, to convert the pattern I want to find on other datasets in a series of values. So for example the OHLC data I posted above would be quantified, somehow, and on another set of OHLC data I would just need to find values that get close to the pattern I want. This approach is very empirical for now and I don't know how to put that in code.

A tool I was suggested to use: [Stumpy](https://pypi.org/project/stumpy/)

**What I need:**
I don't need the exact code, I only need an example, an article, a library or any kind of source that can point me out on how to work when I want to detect a certain pattern specified by me on a OHLC data set. I hope I was specific enough; any kind of advice is appreciated!

Comment: In what way do you want the shape to be similar? Similar mean prices for the day? Similar open/close? Similar max/min? Or some combination of all of the above?

Comment: See the chart I attached and instead of seeing it as a candlestick, see it as a line chart. What I'm trying to do is to take another chart and detect when it becomes similar to the one I choose. So basically I need to tell my code: "detect when price is up and then price goes sideways for some time" in this case

Comment: Since the question was closed, your bounty was refunded. If you edit it to make it more focused and re-offer the bounty, I'd be glad to help further.

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione Yes indeed the question got closed. I made a new one that should be a lot more specific and focused and i will start a bounty for it tomorrow as soon as SO will allow me to. If you want to take a look, so that i can also reward you, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861895/detecting-patterns-from-two-arrays-of-data-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Stumpy](https://pypi.org/project/stumpy/) will work for you.

## Basic Methodology

The basic gist of the algorithm is to compute a [matrix profile](https://stumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial_The_Matrix_Profile.html) of a data stream, and then use that to find areas that are similar. (You can think of the matrix profile as a sliding window that gives a rating of how closely two patters match using [Z-normalized Euclidean Distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnQneYvg84M&feature=youtu.be&t=368)).

[This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-matrix-profiles-5568f3375d90) explains matrix profiles in a pretty straightforward way. Here's an excerpt that explains what you want:

> Simply put, a motif is a repeated pattern in a time series and a discord is an anomaly.
> With the Matrix Profile computed, it is simple to find the top-K number of motifs or
> discords. The Matrix Profile stores the distances in Euclidean space meaning that a
> distance close to 0 is most similar to another sub-sequence in the time series and a
> distance far away from 0, say 100, is unlike any other sub-sequence. Extracting the lowest
> distances gives the motifs and the largest distances gives the discords.

The benefits of using a matrix profile can be found [here](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/MatrixProfile.html).

The gist of what you want to do is compute the matrix profile, then look for minima. Minima mean the sliding window matched another place well.

[This example](https://stumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial_Fast_Approximate_Matrix_Profiles.html) shows how to use it to find repeating patterns in one data set:

[image]

To reproduce their results myself, I navigated to [the DAT file](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/iSAX/steamgen.dat) and downloaded it myself, then opened and read it instead of using their broken `urllib` calls to get the data.

Replace

```
context = ssl.SSLContext()  # Ignore SSL certificate verification for simplicity
url = "https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/iSAX/steamgen.dat"
raw_bytes = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=context).read()
data = io.BytesIO(raw_bytes)
```

with

```
steam_df = None
with open("steamgen.dat", "r") as data:
    steam_df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None, sep="\s+")
```

I also had to add some `plt.show()` calls since I ran it outside of Jupyter. With those tweaks, you can run their example and see how it works.

Here's the full code I used, so you don't have to repeat what I did:

```
import pandas as pd
import stumpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import urllib
import ssl
import io
import os


def change_plot_size(width, height, plt):
    fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
    fig_size[0] = width
    fig_size[1] = height
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
    plt.rcParams["xtick.direction"] = "out"


change_plot_size(20, 6, plt)

colnames = ["drum pressure", "excess oxygen", "water level", "steam flow"]

context = ssl.SSLContext()  # Ignore SSL certificate verification for simplicity
url = "https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/iSAX/steamgen.dat"
raw_bytes = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=context).read()
data = io.BytesIO(raw_bytes)

steam_df = None
with open("steamgen.dat", "r") as data:
    steam_df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None, sep="\s+")


steam_df.columns = colnames
steam_df.head()


plt.suptitle("Steamgen Dataset", fontsize="25")
plt.xlabel("Time", fontsize="20")
plt.ylabel("Steam Flow", fontsize="20")
plt.plot(steam_df["steam flow"].values)
plt.show()

m = 640
mp = stumpy.stump(steam_df["steam flow"], m)
true_P = mp[:, 0]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"hspace": 0})
plt.suptitle("Motif (Pattern) Discovery", fontsize="25")

axs[0].plot(steam_df["steam flow"].values)
axs[0].set_ylabel("Steam Flow", fontsize="20")
rect = Rectangle((643, 0), m, 40, facecolor="lightgrey")
axs[0].add_patch(rect)
rect = Rectangle((8724, 0), m, 40, facecolor="lightgrey")
axs[0].add_patch(rect)
axs[1].set_xlabel("Time", fontsize="20")
axs[1].set_ylabel("Matrix Profile", fontsize="20")
axs[1].axvline(x=643, linestyle="dashed")
axs[1].axvline(x=8724, linestyle="dashed")
axs[1].plot(true_P)


def compare_approximation(true_P, approx_P):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(gridspec_kw={"hspace": 0})

    ax.set_xlabel("Time", fontsize="20")
    ax.axvline(x=643, linestyle="dashed")
    ax.axvline(x=8724, linestyle="dashed")
    ax.set_ylim((5, 28))
    ax.plot(approx_P, color="C1", label="Approximate Matrix Profile")
    ax.plot(true_P, label="True Matrix Profile")
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


approx = stumpy.scrump(steam_df["steam flow"], m, percentage=0.01, pre_scrump=False)
approx.update()
approx_P = approx.P_

seed = np.random.randint(100000)
np.random.seed(seed)
approx = stumpy.scrump(steam_df["steam flow"], m, percentage=0.01, pre_scrump=False)

compare_approximation(true_P, approx_P)

# Refine the profile

for _ in range(9):
    approx.update()

approx_P = approx.P_

compare_approximation(true_P, approx_P)

# Pre-processing

approx = stumpy.scrump(
    steam_df["steam flow"], m, percentage=0.01, pre_scrump=True, s=None
)
approx.update()
approx_P = approx.P_

compare_approximation(true_P, approx_P)
```

## Self join vs. join against target

Note that this example was a "self join", meaning it was looking for repeated patterns in it's own data. You'll want to join with the target you are looking to match.

Looking at the signature of `stumpy.stump` shows you how to do this:

```
def stump(T_A, m, T_B=None, ignore_trivial=True):
    """
    Compute the matrix profile with parallelized STOMP

    This is a convenience wrapper around the Numba JIT-compiled parallelized
    `_stump` function which computes the matrix profile according to STOMP.

    Parameters
    ----------
    T_A : ndarray
        The time series or sequence for which to compute the matrix profile

    m : int
        Window size

    T_B : ndarray
        The time series or sequence that contain your query subsequences
        of interest. Default is `None` which corresponds to a self-join.

    ignore_trivial : bool
        Set to `True` if this is a self-join. Otherwise, for AB-join, set this
        to `False`. Default is `True`.

    Returns
    -------
    out : ndarray
        The first column consists of the matrix profile, the second column
        consists of the matrix profile indices, the third column consists of
        the left matrix profile indices, and the fourth column consists of
        the right matrix profile indices.
```

What you'll want to do is pass the data (pattern) you want to look for as `T_B` and then the larger sets you want to look in as `T_A`. The window size specifies how large of a search area you want (this will probably be the length of your `T_B` data, I'd imagine, or smaller if you want).

Once you have the matrix profile, you will just want to do a simple search and get the indicies of the lowest values. Each window starting at that index is a good match. You may also want to define some threshold minimum such that you only consider it a match if there is at least one value in the matrix profile below that minimum.

Another thing to realize is that your data set is really several correlated data sets (Open, High, Low, Close, and Volume). You'll have to decide which you want to match. Maybe you want a good match just for the opening prices, or maybe you want a good match for all of them. You'll have to decide what a good match means and calculate the matrix for each, then decide what to do if only one or a couple of those subsets match. For example, one data set may match the opening prices well, but close prices don't match as well. Another set's volume may match and that's it. Maybe you'll want to see if the normalized prices match (meaning you'd only be looking at the shape and not the relative magnitudes, i.e. a $1 stock going to $10 would look the same as a $10 one going to $100). All of that is pretty straightforward once you can compute a matrix profile.

Comment: This was very helpful. So there are two thing i'm trying to understand: how can i feed the data to Stumpy? I would just have to turn my OHLC data into a ndarray and just give it to Stumpy? Second thing: you said "normalized data", so don't i need to normalize the data somehow? I mean, if a stock costs $100 and another $1 will it be the same for Stumpy? And what if i normalize my data? Will it be easier for Stumpy to find patterns?

Comment: Last part is exactly what i need to do: i want to only look at the shape; that means i need to apply some sort of normalization, but i don't know how to do that with OHLC data

Comment: You will have to pass each metric as a separate array. For example, first feed it just highs and match those. Then lows, then opens, then closes (the order doesn't matter). If you want to match all of those things, then you'll need a matrix for each and you'll want to detect when all of the matrices give back a low value. If you only care about one or two, then you only have to do those.

Comment: As for normalizing, it sounds like the euclidian distance is already normalized in their algorithm, but they may be meaning something else. It would be easiest to just try both ways and see which gives you a better match. When I say normalize, I just mean scale so the values are all in a similar range.

Comment: This is not documented in the STUMPY tutorials but when you have a known pattern, I recommend following this answer instead which leverages STUMPY's `mass` function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63368206/2955541

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione would you mind elaborating on what you mean when you said "using their broken urllib calls to get the data"? I just executed the example tutorial on end and was successfully able to retrieve the data without any issue.